# FLASK POST: 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED

Tags: python, api, rest, flask

I have a piece of Flask code that should process a POST request. However, I always get a '405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED' error when trying to do a POST

```
@app.route('/get_project_details', methods=['POST'])
def get__project_details():
  print('Got inside')

@app.after_request
def log_the_status_code(response):
  print(request.method)
  print(response.status)
  return response
```

We I run a request on the API we get the following reply:

```
POST
405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED
```

While I expect to see the 'got inside' of course.

Does anyone have an idea on what is going on?

Comment: Can you give more info on the request you made? Like full url, parameters etc.

Comment: which parameters are you looking for? I'll need to check this on Monday with the front end people :-D
But at least, we can see the connection coming in.. Since when I add request.path, it is 'dev.blabla.com/get_project_details', so it seems the error doesn't coming from a wrong path.

Comment: Are you sure you run `post` request and not `get` or any other request?? Because the error clearly says that the method you are running is not allowed.